# How do you initialize a stack to be empty in java?

Tags: java, stack

I'm given

```
   private Stack<Double> stack
```

When creating the default constructor I'm asked as follows:

```
  "Initialize stack to be an empty Stack to hold double data values"
```

I've tried something along the lines of stack.empty() but I'm guessing empty() functions the same as isEmpty() which isn't much help. Does anyone know how to initialize an empty stack?

Comment: `stack = new Stack<>();`?

Comment: Well first I'd start with the "initialize a Stack" part of the problem, which is `new Stack<>()`.  Then, I'd look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html#%3Cinit%3E()) for the Stack constructor, and I'd see it says "Creates an empty Stack."  Great!  It's already empty, so I don't need to do anything else.  To be honest, it doesn't look like you put very much effort into your question, as you haven't posted any attempt.  Next time you should post what you've tried and what your research turned up.

Comment: And if your Java teacher did not explain in the first lesson where to find the Java documentation online and how it is organized ... **complain**.  It is important information that should be presented to all new Java students, as early as possible.  And certainly, before they are given their first programming exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a [Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html) object is created it is empty by default. So a mere

```java
private Stack<Double> stack = new Stack<>();
```

would be enough to initialize it empty.

You can also initialize the stack in the constructor of your class if you don't want to separate its declaration and initialization:

```java
class YourClass {
  private Stack<Double> stack;

  public YourClass() {
    this.stack = new Stack<>();
  }

}
```